# How to dynamically change animation value in inline syle of ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I found many related questions regarding inline style of ReactJS but non suitable to mine.

I need to change the animation speed(1,3,4,6,7 are my animation speeds) in UI as per the API values (which changes dynamically)

I tried the following way

```
<img className="fan1" src={fan1} style={{animation: "spin "`${2}`"s linear infinite" }}></img>    
<img className="fan1" src={fan1} style={{animation: "spin ${2}s linear infinite" }}></img>
<img className="fan1" src={fan1} style={{animation: `spin {2}s linear infinite` }}></img>
<img className="fan1" src={fan1} style={{animation: {spin {2}s linear infinite} }}></img>
```

I'm not sure how to acheive this. Please help me out.

Comment: Every single one of those is invalid or incorrect Javascript string syntax lol. Read this _carefully_ and check examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals  and revisit basic Javsacript string syntax

Comment: @Jayce444 post that link, i'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
<img className="fan1" 
      src={fan1}
      style={{ animation: `spin ${5}s linear infinite` }}
      alt="fan"
  ></img>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that the style strings are not valid JavaScript. May I suggest reading up on the syntax on [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). If you change that I suspect it should then work. So your code should look something like this,

```js
<img className="fan1" src={fan1} style={{animation: `spin ${2}s linear infinite` }}></img>    
<img className="fan1" src={fan1} style={{animation: `spin ${2}s linear infinite`  }}></img>
<img className="fan1" src={fan1} style={{animation: `spin ${2}s linear infinite`  }}></img>
<img className="fan1" src={fan1} style={{animation: `spin ${2}s linear infinite`  }}></img>
```

You loud then replace the `${2}` with a link to the state that is constantly being updated.